# C# - Console.WriteLine() does not showing the second Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, console

While working on the C# Basic datatypes when I made 2 bool variables using different methods and as I tried to show them using Console.WriteLine() method, first variable was displayed but 2nd one did't display. 
I know the alternates to get the desired output by just using the + symbol between variables or using Placeholder syntax in Console.WriteLine,but I just want to know the reason, why the 2nd parameter is not showing ? If someone know the reason do answer.

this is the code that I'm working on.

```
        bool b1 = true;
        System.Boolean b2 = new System.Boolean();
        b2 = false;
        Console.WriteLine( b1.ToString() , b2.ToString() );
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documenation for `Console.WriteLine`? The overload you're calling doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` works as `String.Format`:

- 1st parameter: Format string.
- 2nd to nth: arguments to be used by
  format string.

This is what you need to do:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", b1, b2);
```

Comment: Adding to this - it would be worth your while looking into [`Composite Formatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is there a format string, which prints all arguments?

Answer (score 1):

check that what the way to write overloading function in this .net framworkand alternative is that:

Console.WriteLine(b1);
Console.WriteLine(b2);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation from Console. I think you thought that the parameters were (string, string), but it is actually (string, object).

```
        // Summary:
        //     Writes the text representation of the specified object, followed by the current
        //     line terminator, to the standard output stream using the specified format
        //     information.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   format:
        //     A composite format string (see Remarks).
        //
        //   arg0:
        //     An object to write using format.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   System.IO.IOException:
        //     An I/O error occurred.
        //
        //   System.ArgumentNullException:
        //     format is null.
        //
        //   System.FormatException:
        //     The format specification in format is invalid.
        public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The overload you're calling is intended to take a format string as the first parameter and an object to use in the format string as the second parameter.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx

What you should be doing is calling Console.WriteLine twice:

```
Console.WriteLine(b1);
Console.WriteLine(b2);
```

Answer (score -4):

This is what you trying to do in your Program:
 `Console.WriteLine(b1.ToString(),b2.ToString());`

The first argument accepts the format and the second argument accepts the object to show, in your case you providing the object to show but in your first (format) argument you are not specifying where to show, it's taking your object but unable to show it in the console, because you didn't specify that thing, in C# you can specify that in couple of different ways

```
Console.WriteLine(b1.ToString()+ " {0}", b2.ToString());
Console.WriteLine($"{b1.ToString()} {b2.ToString()}"); 
Console.WriteLine(b1.ToString() + " " + b2.ToString());
```

Comment: No offense -  you're basically putting a square peg in a round hole with these implementations; despite being _technically_ valid, it completely undermines the whole methodology behind overloading. With that said, they are valid approaches; despite being highly unlikely to be used the real world scenario - saving some twisted requirement I cannot think of now.

Comment: FYI: You don't need to explicitly call `ToString()` when using composite formatting; it's implied. Also, that first one is just a *really really bad* idea and definitely not a habit to get into.