# Why my code doesn't print any result?

Tags: c#

What i am basically trying to do is *subtract* or *add up* `2` numbers by using a `switch` statement. I know I can't do it way more efficiently, but I'm not into that stuff yet (since I googled how i would go about doing this, it got a lot of different experienced ways).
I came up with the following piece of code, i used some references on Microsoft's website and some google stuff.

But i cannot get it to work, it works to some extent but it never gives me an answer.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Type number 1: ");
            int line1 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Type number 2: ");
            int line2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("1 = +");
            Console.WriteLine("2 = -");
            int formula = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (formula)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Answer is ", (line1 + line2));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Answer is ", (line1 - line2));
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose 1 or 2");
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, it only shows

```
"Answer is "
```

Where does it go wrong?

Comment: So, what's the problem you're having?

Comment: possibly the most pointless question title ever.

Comment: That question doesn't deserve negative votes -  at least with the edit.

Comment: If that is your opinion, vote as you like, but don't force other users to think like you @gobes

Comment: aw guys come on, leave him alone, hes new to programming we've all been there. shouldn't be putting him done hahahaha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Console.WriteLine() does not showing the second Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493534/c-sharp-console-writeline-does-not-showing-the-second-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify where the value should be inserted in the format string. Now your value is simply ignored. You can do it in multiple ways:

```
Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0}", (line1 + line2));
```

The `{0}` denotes the place where the first parameter should be inserted. (So the next one would be `{1}`, etc.)

The C# 6, and a little safer way:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Answer is {line1 + line2}");
```

Answer (score 6):

Add *formatting*, i.e. *where* `{0}` withing the string the system should put the answer:

```
Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0}", (line1 + line2));

...

Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0}", (line1 - line2));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can either write

Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0}", (line1 + line2));

or (which is not as pretty)

Console.WriteLine("Answer is " + (line1 + line2));
//I dont recommend the latter one, if you dont have a string in the first part
but an int it might just add them depending on how you wrote that..

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell where to insert your second parameter, your string

```
Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0}", (line1 + line2));
```

This tells Console.WriteLine to insert the first parameter where you place "{0}".
With more arguments, you need to increase the index, i.e.

```
Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0} {1}", "not", "here"); //displays "Answer is not here"
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx).
Another hint: all parameters are automatically converted to string, so you dont need to cast them manually.